# Did Naruto's children inherit Kurama's chakra?

Tags: naruto

I'm just wondering: how did Boruto and Himawari obtain the Kurama's chakra?

Did they inherit Kurama's chakra? Or did they obtain it in a way like the Gold and Silver Brothers did, by eating a piece of Kurama's chakra?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know, really. So far Kishimoto hasn't really shown anything aside from them inheriting Naruto's whisker marks, which he had most likely got from Kurama being sealed in Kushina when she was pregnant (if you look closely at Kurama, he has the same exact whisker marks on his cheeks though wilder looking). So they might have inherited some influence from him through genetics, but not a lot since Hinata was the one carrying them.

Mostly I think they more inherited the Uzumaki genes (and clearly Hyuga) and maybe a diluted bit of Kurama's chakra since the Double Tetragram Seal was supposed to steadily siphon it into Naruto's system, but I don't know if that's still the case after the war and Rikudou Sennin's interference.

So the effect might have just been larger reserves, which would be hard to tell when Uzumaki have inherently huge reserves.

(Though on another note, it would be cool if that meant Himawari could use the chakra chains like Kushina and Karin, since it seems to be a female trait).

Comment: the chains I wouldnt put as a female trait. orochimaru during the war mentioned something that made it sound like the chais are an uzumaki general trait when they try to protect loved ones (and naruto had his tails so he didnt need chains)

Comment: That's a good point. So then I guess the chains would be a bit more like the Sharingan in the series. We only see Uchiha men and Kakashi with it, but don't rule out the possibility that Mikoto and other Kunoichi may have developed it in their careers that we just never got to see. Particularly since it's awakened by high emotional moments such as a life or death senario. So then I guess it's possible Boruto could develop the chains too.

Comment: Possible we sadly have too few infos on that though. but the chains would make sense that naruto doesnt use them as he has his tails while the other uzumaki didnt

Answer (score 0):

The whiskers from chakra influence is accurate. It was stated in one of the episodes of kakashi saga "when a female jinchuriki is pregnant chakra flows to the fetus. So thats how naruto got them. As for his kids. It is possible maybe hinata was pregnant and got in a fight with naruto sparing her chakra like in the war vs 10 tails. Or the possibility of neing around his chakra so much. However it is unlikely they got chakra from kuruma. Unless it was in sperm. Though we never got intel on children of male jinchuriki.

Comment: However in all actuality figurimg out how or if they got the chakra or if its just genetic appearence you cannot proove much of anythimg but speculate. As someone said we are not the makers of naruto so we dont know if it iant stated in tje anime or movies. All we do know is the whiskers "appear to be."" a effect of kurrama's chakra shown by the twins and naruto.  The possibility of his kids inheritimg some of the fox chakra are unconfirmed. But i assume because it frlows in a female reproductiom area it is likely it could in males to.

Answer (score -3):

Most probably yes!! We can clearly see whom ever directly touched by Kurama chakra is getting a whiskers like mark on their faces.

1. Gold and silver brothers have it due to eating Kurama's chakra directly from its belly.
2. Naruto has it.
3. Boruto and Himawari have it.

And even though they have the marks, I do not think they have an large portion of it. Probably even less then the Gold and Silver brothers

**Theory of the whiskers (this is only my speculation how the whisker mark came to be)**

So we can clearly see whisker marks on most of the people who have been in contact with Kurama's chakra.

The Gold and silver brothers have them due to eating large amounts of the Bijuu's chakra directly from its belly. And Naruto? By being the Jinchuriki? although Kushina did not have them when she was a Jinchuriki.

So my guess is ,it is getting by the natural insertion of Bijuu or in this case Kurama chakra in to your body.even though a jinchuriki has a Bijuu inside their body its not a natural fusion of chakra, its done by a artificial sealing method.So that's why Kushina or any other Bijuu holder do not have a distinct features on their bodies.

Then the Question is how did Naruto get the whisker mark?. even though Naruto is a Jinchuriki and Kurama sealed within him, he got whisker mark way before becoming a jinchuriki .He got the whisker mark from the born or,when inside His mother's womb.Even though jinchuriki has a seal we all know smaller amount of chakra can leaked out form a jinchuriki . So when Naruto is still a fetus(or even Kushina 's eggs and all) He had the influence of the Kurama chakra and this caused the natural fusion of Kurama chakra, this is the reason Naruto got his whisker mark.

This theory also can apply for Boruto and Himawari Due to passing Kurama chakra via Kurama chakra infused sperm.

**P.S.>->** 
  we do not get to see many jinchuriki offspring's.We only get to see Naruto,Boruto and Himawari ,as people who are born from a jinchuriki  parent and they are all jinchuriki of Kurama.I think if other jinchuriki had children they will too have distinctive features from the get go.

Comment: But how did Boruto and Himawari obtain the chakra. Naruto also got born without the 9 tails chakra. And IIRC had the whiskers even before he became one (which btw is totally unrelated to the question the OP asked)

Comment: @Dimitrimx read my theory, it explains how Boruto and Himawari obtain the whiskers  and how Naruto got it.

Comment: The question is not about the whiskers. But how they obtained the chakra. If you managed to corralate those 2 within 1 question then first of all provide some proof, not just speculation. And try some proper sentence building, as I can't detect any piece stating where Boruto and Himawari got the chakra.

Comment: @Dimitrimx well sorry about my English. but i can not give out definite proof of my theory, because i am not the creator of Naruto and in my theory i made my speculation based on facts .so its not that far off.And whiskers are related to Kurama chakra ,that's what i'm trying to tell